# changing color of value of <input type="submit">

Tags: html, css

How can I change the color of the `value` attribute of `<input type="submit">`?

```
<input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="enviar_btn" />
```

css

```
.enviar_btn {
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: #0a1e4c;
    font: #939595;
}
```

Comment: CSS runs in client and knows nothing about server side code responsible for generating the HTML output. To focus questions on CSS experts, you'd best just ask about the JSF-generated HTML output instead of JSF source code. Just rightclick page in browser and do *View Source* to extract the relevant HTML output and base your question on it. Once you get the answer, then it's merely a matter of writing JSF code in such way that it generates exactly the desired HTML/CSS output. Nonetheless, it wouldn't be a bad idea to go through a [basic CSS tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `color: green` in your code. You CSS should look like this:

```
.enviar_btn {
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: #0a1e4c;
    font: #939595;
    color: green
}
```

You can find more information about the `color` property [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_color.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the text color? E. g. set "color: red" in css.